# Remote access remote file server using other window account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

when I tried to access my remote file server and tried to using

```
if (!Directory.Exists('//remoteserver/file')) 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
```

the program throw exception said incorrect username and password.

I checked my local window domain is different with the remote server. Can I create temperate win authentication with new domain to access in asp.net?

or  any other way can resolve it.

Comment: Look at ASP.NET Impersonation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx - also check to see how your IIS server is configured for the Anonymous Authentication and Application Pool identity options.

Comment: I do not think it is the impersonation's problem. if it is impersonation problem that program should give me message said server denied. otherwise, I tried add impersonate in my config, but it still does not work. I think it just the windows authntication's problem that program send current local win acocunt to remote but remote's does not have this account and password.